# Master denying the bloodline of his offspring born to his concubine

Tags: fiqh, children, slavery

Can the master deny the bloodline of his offspring born to his concubine? If he is within ignorance of the bloodline, can he still have intimate relations with her even if the parentage is obvious? Likewise, if he is not within ignorance of the bloodline, if he can legally have intimate relations with her, is he held liable in the eyes of Allah? How does this all apply to a supposed marriage? Do the same concepts of ignorance of bloodline and intimacy coincide with marriage as well? Lastly, since his denial of the bloodline of his offspring would essentially equate to adultery, would the master be allowed to immediately to discipline her according to the sharia? If he can't, and the bloodline is obvious, then can the qadi discharge the claim themselves? I can't help but feel like this ruling of a master denying the bloodline of his offspring born to a concubine creates a massive amount of problems. Why is this allowed in the first place?

Comment: This whole post is a bunch of questions? In order to answer a post adequately you should stick on asking one question per post (see in [our meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/why-we-should-avoid-asking-multi-question-questions)). Further is your question "
Can the master deny the bloodline of his offspring born to his concubine?" really a question or a claim since at the end of your post you take it as given while it isn't.

Comment: It's mainly a question, but after that question, I presuppose that if it is the case, then I format a set of different questions for it.